# NSData to file PHP

Tags: php, iphone, parsing, webserver, nsdata

I have NSData that I am 'POST'ing to a PHP file on my site, from that NSData, I am writing it to a file. However, the file's contents are the string of NSData (range of letters and numbers) rather than the parsed data. How can I parse the NSData to a string in PHP and then write the contents of that string to a file?

Here is my code so far:

```
$filename = $_POST['username'] . "_iCal_" . $newID . ".ics";
$File = $upload_path . $filename; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = urldecode($_POST['ical']);
$Data = str_replace (" ", "", $Data);
fwrite($Handle, $Data) or die("s");
fclose($Handle) or die("s");


[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:event] //event is an NSObj-- Subclass with NSCoding etc... implemented
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MPiCalUpload_URL]];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:MPiCalRetriever_timeout];
[request setPostValue:_username forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:data forKey:@"ical"];
```

Comment: Please post the part where you place your NSData into the query. The error might as well be there. Also, you don't typically need to `urldecode()` the POST variables.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, its been added.

Comment: Docs on ASIFormDataRequest seems to be lacking... See if it Base64-encodes the passed NSData. That would easily produce a bunch "letters and numbers" instead of file.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev It looks the same as if you NSLog a NSData variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider passing the data as a Base64 string. Search SO for "NSData Base64", you'll find plenty of examples. Then on the PHP side, use base64_decode() to get the bytes back.